# concatenate strings

Tags: string, algorithm, perl

I have a big problem with my design of my algorith because i use large text file.
I have a text file that contains sequences of words.
eg

1. my friends
2. hello my friends
3. the world

and a second file is large (gigabyte) containing sentences.
The goal of the program is through the words (the first file) word by word and look in the second file the concatenate the symbol "+"

for example
"**hello my friends of the world" as input**" Become
"**hello + my + friends**  of **the+world**"

Any idea please?
I want to program it in Perl wich is performant with text

i've done this script in Perl, but its too slow because it read the file Many time..:(
This is an example of Perl programm, it works , but it is too slow

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature qw(:5.10); 
my ($in, $dico) = @ARGV;
die "Bad infile $in" if !-r $in;
die "Bad dicofile $dico" if !-r $dico;

# load dico
my @dico;
open(FICHIERNOUVELLES, ">resultat7.txt");
open my $DICO, "<", $dico or die "Can't open $dico for reading: $!\n";
# For all lines in the Dico
foreach my $line (<$DICO>) {
chomp($line);
# extract words
 if (my @word = split /\s+/, $line) {

 my $re = q{(^\s*|\s+)(}.(join q(\s+), map quotemeta, @word).q{)(\s+|\s*$)};

push @dico, qr/$re/;
}
}

 open my $IN, "<", $in or die "Can't open $in for reading: $!\n";
 my @word;

foreach my $line (<$IN>) {

 foreach my $dico (@dico) {

  while (my (undef, $sequence) = $line =~ /$dico/) {

  $sequence =~ s/\s+/+/g;
  $line =~ s/$dico/$1$sequence$3/;
  }
 }
print FICHIERNOUVELLES "$line";

 }
close(FICHIERNOUVELLES);
```

Comment: This is my understanding of your question. first file has set of words and second file has sentences. And after each word in second file which is present in the file you have to add + symbol. Am i right?

Comment: can you show us your code? also a minimal example of the two input files and what the output for those input files should look like?

Comment: Thznk you, i edit my post

Comment: OK, I think I got it... he wants to find strings of words (defined in file 1) in the second file, and replace " " with " + " for each instance of such string in a second file.

Comment: yes, it is , its conatenates words with "+"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to not read the second file multiple times is to read the sets of words from file1 first, and store in a data structure.

```
use File::Slurp;
my @lines = read_file($filename1);
my %replacements = map { my $c = $_; $c =~ s/ / + /g; ( $_ => $c ) } @lines; 

open (my $file2, "<", $filename2) or die "$!";
while (<$file2>) {
    chomp;
    foreach my $replacement (keys %replacements) {
        s/$replacement/$replacements{$replacement}/g;
    }
    print $_;
}
```

Comment: I would sort %replacements by decreasing length: `foreach my $replacement (sort {length($b) <=> length($a)} keys(%replacements))`. This way "hello my friends" will get matched before "my friends"

Comment: First af all, Thak you DVK for your help, I test your script, but there is errors  _./test.pl: ligne 1: use : commande introuvable
./test.pl: ligne 2: use : commande introuvable
./test.pl: ligne 3: use : commande introuvable
./test.pl: ligne 4: Erreur de syntaxe près du symbole inattendu « ( »
./test.pl: ligne 4: `use feature qw(:5.10); '
-

Comment: @user17241: did you add the line `#!/usr/bin/perl` (or whatever path to perl you have) in the beginning?

Comment: you probably do not have File::Slurp installed.

Comment: @user17241 - you can easily emulate read_file (if you don't feel like troubleshooting File::Slurp) with `my @lines;open(my $f,"<",$name) or die""; while (<$f>) { push @lines, $_ }; close($f);`

Comment: ok Thanks, it compiles well, but i cannot see changes :( "reprise de la sessionje déclare je déclare reprise la session"